# to pip or not to pip for Raspberry Pi Wheezy

Tags: ros, wheezy, raspberrypi, pip, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing ROS on a Raspberry Pi with the Raspian wheezy distro using these instructions: [ROS_RaspPi](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi)
and the [debian build](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian).

The instructions worked OK up to but not including step 1.5, Build Higher-level/tools (Layer 2), which apparently is just the way it is.

Anyway, while setting up the environment, I tried to make an overlay and the instructions fail with
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall which generates:
unable to locate package python-rosinstall
Turns out, that is OK, as rosws was already installed via pip.

But that led to a bigger question-- is it OK to use both pip and apt-get install in the debian build for raspberry pi?

Searching ros answers [overlay creation](http://answers.ros.org/question/44186/how-do-i-solve-fuerte-overlay-creation-problem/), it seems this may be due to using pip and apt-get install in the same build.

In the debian build instructions, it says:
First install rosinstall and rospkg using pip install (advanced options for pip install):
sudo pip install -U rosinstall vcstools rospkg rosdep

but there is a [note](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=88517&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20) from Tully on August 5th, saying not to do that, but I am wondering if his note applies only to bigger distros like Ubuntu:
"If you have previously installed using pip it is recommended to uninstall
using pip the tools now available through apt. I will attach instructions
for uninstalling these tools below.

These tools include, rospkg, rosdep, rosinstall, vcstools, and rosrelease.
In apt they are named python-PACKAGENAME, such as python-rospkg."

What to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45224/to-pip-or-not-to-pip-for-raspberry-pi-wheezy/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2012-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, I would say if you can, always use the installation mechanism of your distro. Currently, only Ubuntu i386 and amd64 are supported. On any other platform you need to use pip.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-10-08**:
It's ok to use apt and pip in the same installation.  Just make sure to keep the pip stuff up to date when you update from apt.  Using the two install methods leads to packages getting out of sync as often the user only remembers to update one of them.